Order Statistics from a sum of exponential distributions
Let $X_i$ $(X_1, \dots, X_n)$ and $Y_i (Y_1, \dots,Y_n)$ be i.i.d. exponential r.vs with rate $\lambda$. Let $Z_i= X_i+Y_i$.
How to write the pdf of the k-th order statistics of the $Z_i$ random variable ?

Please use MathJax whenever you type a formula on this site. It’s pretty easy. You just enclose your formulae into the $ signs, for the most part.

If $X_i, Y_i\sim \exp(\lambda)$ then $Z_i = X_i + Y_i$ has pdf of
$$f_{Z_i}(z) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X_i}(x)f_{Y_i}(z-x) dx = \int_0^z \lambda^2 e^{-\lambda x}e^{-\lambda(z-x)} dx = \lambda^2 e^{-\lambda z}z$$
And thus its CDF is
$$F_{Z_i}(z) = \int_0^z \lambda^2 e^{-\lambda x}x dx = 1-e^{-\lambda z} (\lambda  z+1)$$
In general, the probability density function of the $k$-th order statistic $Z_{(k)}$ of $n$ i.i.d random variables from $Z$ is
$$f_{Z_{(k)}}(z) = \frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!} F_Z(z)^{k-1} (1-F_Z(z))^{n-k} f_Z(z)$$
Plugging in, we get
$$f_{Z_{(k)}}(z) = \frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!} \cdot \left(1-e^{-\lambda z} (\lambda  z+1)\right)^{k-1} \cdot \left(e^{-\lambda z} (\lambda  z+1) \right)^{n-k} \cdot \lambda^2 e^{-\lambda z}z$$
Where you expecting a simple closed form?
